# How to execute new bash command inside shell script file?

Tags: linux, shell, subshell

How can I put the follow script to work properly?

```bash
1  #/bin/bash
2
3  # some commands
4
5  bash
6  # a lot of commands
7  # ...
8  exit
9  
10 bash
11 # A lot of other commands
12 # ...
13 exit
14 
15 exit 0
```

The problem is that when executing the script in shell, a new interactive bash shell is entered and the execution stopped right there waiting for standard input. As the sub-environment may not be BASH in practice, `bash` command in line 4 and 9 are just examples and that's why I need a new solution other than putting those commands into separate files and invoke.

Comment: The question is not very clear - may be some actual code and results will help. You may however define these code snippets as functions and call the function in background - so the rest of the code will execute - check out https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Putting_functions_in_background

Comment: What do you actually want to do? It is very unclear to me why you would like to call for `bash` within a bash-script.

Comment: Thanks Sharad but function probably not the way as it cannot provide with a new executing environment. Actually when using rootless container with buildah, "buildah unshare" must be used to enter the user namespace and then do some mount and chroot things. As bash/buildah unshare/chroot are all creating/entering new sub-environment and all of them has syntax like "bash/buildah unshare/chroot -- COMMAND" where COMMAND can be any legal command or valid script(files). If script file is not prefered, any other way to execute multi-commands one-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour. If you execute a mere `bash`, you get an interactive shell. If you want to run several bash commands  in a child process - which probably is what you want, since you tagged your question *subshell*, you write

```
bash FILENAME
```

where FILENAME is the name of the file which contains the commands. If you want to run several bash commands inside the current process, you write one of

```
source FILENAME
. FILENAME
```

The differences between `source` and `.` are minor, and you find them described in the bash *man* page.

If you want to run several commands in a child process, without putting them into a separate file, you can do it with

```
(
   some command
   some other command
)
```

Comment: Thanks, well I would name it as sub-environment which is more reasonable and executing bash in a bash script indeed create a subshell which is also kind of sub-environment. To be simpler (for sub-environment such as bash/buildah unshare/chroot etc.), I code the way my snippet appears above, but it fails to work as expected...

Comment: The Unix / Linux term for this is a **process**. A process **is** not an environment, but it **holds** an environment. Of course you can create your own terminology, if you want, but you risk being misunderstood when discussing technical issues with your co-workers.

Comment: @BlaneJohn : See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-processes.htm). I suggest that you familiarize yourself with the process model und Unix, because if you don't, you will get into trouble sooner or later when writing i.e. shell programs.